# Scroll View & UIGestureRecogniser Conflict

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIImageView as subview in my scrollView.

I want to be able to pan up/down on UIImage to adjust the color of the UIImage.

Also I want to be able to pan/zoom around the image(that's why I implemented scrollView).

I have an adjustColor IBAction UIButton which adds the UIPanGestureRecogniser as target and executes the function below:

```
  func panned(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer){
  ...
  }
```

My problem is that the adjustColor button is ignored by scrollView's scroll behaviour.

If I delete the scrollview and add the UIImage, the adjustColor button activates the color adjustment function and the gestures work perfectly.

On the other hand, if I have the scrollview and the image as subviewimage, my adjustColor button has no functionality.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to connect the UIGestureRecognizer IBOutlet with scrollview.